# Remove the duplicate values and combinations in html select option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamically generated `<select>` field with `<option>`.

```
<select>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value=""> False</option>
    <option value=""> True</option>
    <option value="">False False</option>
    <option value="">False True</option>
    <option value="">True</option>
    <option value="">True True</option>
</select>
```

I would like to remove the duplicate occurrences and combinations. The final `<select>` field with `<option>` should look like :

```
<select>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="">False</option>
    <option value="">True</option>
</select>
```

Here is how my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shabeer90/3f2o81ro/) looks like. Been trying to solve this for hours.

```
var values = [];

$("select").children().each(function() {
  if (values.length > 0) {
    var notExists = false;
    for (var x = 0; x < values.length; x++) {
      var _text = this.text.replace(/\s/g, "");
      var value = values[x].replace(/\s/g, "");

      if (values[x].length > _text.length) {
        //console.log('>>+', value, ' || ', _text, value.indexOf(_text))
        notExists = value.indexOf(_text) > -1 ? true : false;
      } else {
        //console.log('>>*', value, ' || ', _text, _text.indexOf(value))
        notExists = _text.indexOf(value) > -1 ? true : false;
      }
    }
    if (notExists) {
      //this.remove();
      values.push(this.text);
    }
  } else {
    values.push(this.text);
  }
});
```

Any help to solve this is appreciated.

Comment: Just FYI all those `option` elements have identical values. The tricky part of the logic here is excluding the `False False` and `True True` values. What's the logic there? Exclude when it's a repeated word that's already been counted?

Comment: Yes, I removed them for tests purposes, will add them back

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: The logic is that, when you loop through the select options, you will get unique items first. Then its starts creating combinations which I want to remove later on. My select options can only be `blank, True, False`. It cannot have the combinations `False False` , `False True` or `True True`. Does that make sense?

Comment: Are `True` and `False` guaranteed to be in the list? If not, then what happens if you have `False False` but no `False`? Also, couldn't you just remove anything with a space character that is not at the start or end?

Comment: @squint : The first few elements will always be to what I set them as. In this case I have set `True` and `False`, so yes will be guranteed. The remaining elements will always be combinations of `True` and `False`

Comment: In that case, wouldn't anything beyond the first few always be the ones to removed?

Comment: ...seems like `$("select > option").filter(function(el) {
      return el.text.trim().indexOf(' ') === -1
    });` is all you need, given your criteria.

Comment: Not sure your logic makes much sense.  Will it only be true/false values or are these only for demo in the question (in which case different values would make this clear).  If they're generated dynamically, can't you change *how* they're generated and not create the duplicates?   Can you give them values and then remove duplicate values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map()` to return all options text and use `split()` on white-space. Then to remove duplicates you can use `reduce()` to return object. Then you can empty `select` and use `Object.keys()` to loop each property and append to `select`.

```js
var opt = $("select option").map(function() {
  return $(this).text().split(' ')
}).get();

opt = opt.reduce(function(o, e) {return o[e] = true, o}, {});

$('select').empty();
Object.keys(opt).forEach(function(key) {
  $('select').append(' <option value="">'+key+'</option>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="">False</option>
  <option value="">True</option>
  <option value="">False False</option>
  <option value="">False True</option>
  <option value="">True</option>
  <option value="">True True</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This is one of those situations where jQuery's quirky `.map()` actually comes in handy. Though destroying the old elements and creating new ones can cause problems if there are other attributes or data associated with the originals that need to be retained.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through each of this children text , then use [**substring**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) to get the first text & put it in an array.

Once done  [**empty**](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) the select element and append the newly created options

```
var _textHolder=[]; // NA empty array to hold unique text
var _options="";
$("select").children().each(function(item,value) {
  var _textVal = $(this).text().trim(); // Remove white space
  //get the first text content
  var _getText = _textVal.substr(0, _textVal.indexOf(" "));
  // if this text is not present in array then push it   
  if(_textHolder.indexOf(_getText) ==-1){
       _textHolder.push(_getText)
      }
   });
   // Create new options with items from _textHolder
  _textHolder.forEach(function(item){
  _options+='<option value="">'+item+'</option>'
 })
// Empty current select element and append new options
   $('select').empty().append(_options);
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/3f2o81ro/4/)

Answer (score 1):

I would do with pure JS ES6 style. This is producing a words array from the whitespace separated options element's `innerText` value regardless the words are in the front, middle or the end; and it will create a unique options list from that. Basically we are concatenating these arrays and getting it unified by utilizing the new Set object. The code is as follows;

```js
var opts = document.querySelector("select").children,
    list = Array.prototype.reduce.call(opts, function(s,c){
                                               text = c.innerText.trim().split(" ");
                                               return new Set([...s].concat(text)) // adding multiple elements to a set
                                             },new Set());
list = [...list];  // turn set to array
for (var i = opts.length-1; i >= 0; i--){ //reverse iteration not to effect indices when an element is deleted
  i in list ? opts[i].innerText = list[i]
            : opts[i].parentNode.removeChild(opts[i]);
}
```

```html
<select>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value=""> False</option>
    <option value=""> True</option>
    <option value="">False False</option>
    <option value="">False True</option>
    <option value="">True</option>
    <option value="">True True</option>
</select>
```